# Play Framework and custom http headers. How to?

Tags: http, header, playframework, nullpointerexception, playframework-1.x

I need to send custom HTTP header with login information to my play application (play 1.2.5). That custom header is added by filter.

Problem is that play always throws  NullPointerException when I attempt to read:

```
String loggedUser = request.headers.get("loggeduser").value();
```

I have also a servlet for testing, where following prints vale from header correctly.

```
out.println(request.getHeader("loggeduser"));
```

Am I missing something in play?

Thanks

**EDIT**: This is my **filter**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    CustomHeaderWrapper wrapper = new CustomHeaderWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
    String username = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRemoteUser();
    wrapper.addHeader("loggeduser", username);
    chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
}
```

And **CustomHeaderWrapper**:

```
private Map<String, String> customHeaderMap = null;

public CustomHeaderWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    customHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

@Override
public String getHeader(String name) {
    String header = super.getHeader(name);
    return (header != null) ? header : this.getParameter(name);
}

@Override
public Enumeration getHeaderNames() {
    List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
    names.addAll(Collections.list(super.getParameterNames()));
    return Collections.enumeration(names);
}

@Override
public String getParameter(String name) {
    String paramValue = super.getParameter(name); // query Strings
    if (paramValue == null) {
        paramValue = customHeaderMap.get(name);
    }
    return paramValue;
}

public void addHeader(String headerName, String headerValue) {
    customHeaderMap.put(headerName, headerValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a little test project, and used the line of code from your question.  It works perfectly.  I used the [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) plugin for Chrome to set the header.

Remember that all headers are converted to lowercase, before they are added to the `request.headers` hashmap.  So if you placed `"loggedUser"` inside `request.headers.get()`, it would never work.

Comment: Thanks, I used all lowercase. I have edited question ant put there code which adds this custom header. Filter mapping has url pattern to /* <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>